# Google analytics opt out "how to"

Tags: ios, sdk, google-analytics-api

I'm looking to implement google analytics in my app and would like to notify the users of that.
I've been going through all the questions here but can't still find the proper way to do it.

I m using the SDK 3 from google developer website.

There it states:

```
 // Get the app-level opt out preference.
if ([GAI sharedInstance].optOut) {
  ... // Alert the user they have opted out.
}
To set the app-level opt out, use:

// Set the app-level opt out preference.
[[GAI sharedInstance] setOptOut:YES];
```

but nothing more on how to do this...

Any ideas please?

Comment: why not simply open an UIAlertView with a correspondending message ?

Comment: yes. i can do that. that s not a problem. my problem is how to tell whether a user pressed the "Opt In" or "Opt Out" button in my alert view, and how to log this as well

Comment: with the UIAlertViewDelegate you can check which button was pressed and store the value as NSUserDefault value so that it will be accesable when the app starts again...

Comment: yes. I'm wondering how could i do this (store value and sync) when starting up...

Comment: What I am doing at the moment (not working) is: on my app delegate.m NSUserDefaults *googleAnalytics;  - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
.... [googleAnalytics synchronize];

Comment: - (IBAction) toggleEnabledTextForSwitch1onSomeLabel: (id) sender {
    if (optOutSwitch.on) { 
        googleAnalytics = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"OptOutValue"];
        [[GAI sharedInstance] setOptOut:OptOutValue];
        [googleAnalytics synchronize];
    }
    else{
        googleAnalytics = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:NO forKey:@"OptOutValue"];
        [[GAI sharedInstance] setOptOut:OptOutValue];
        [googleAnalytics synchronize];
 }}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an UIAlertView and UIAlertViewDelegate to decide, which buttons the user tapped (opt-in or out). store that in NSUserDefaults.

when checking the result of alertview do:

```
NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSString *allowGoogle;
if (//User tapped opt in) {
    allowGoogle = @"yes";
} else {
    allowGoogle = @"no";
}
[userDefaults setValue:allowGoogle forKey:@"AllowGoogleAnalytics"];
[userDefaults synchronize];
```

place the next code around the UIAlertView open:

```
NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSString *allowGoogle = [userDefaults valueForKey:@"AllowGoogleAnalytics"];
if (!allowGoogle) {
    // HERE OPEN ALERTVIEW because you have no value for that key in your
    // userdefaults
} else {
    if ([allowGoogle isEqualToString:@"yes"] {
        // Enable GoogleAnalytics
    } else {
        // Disable GoogleAnalytics
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks. i was trying to set the [GAI sharedInstance].optOut myBool and then check the [GAI sharedInstance].optOut if YES or NO.

Comment: I will post my complete code below for other members to see. Thanks again